# Как отсортировать QuerySet по полю ,,OneToOneField,,?

Tags: python, django

Требуется: отсортировать QuerySet по полю зависимой ,,OneToOneField,, записи.

,,родительская,, модель

```
class productModel(models.Model):
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField('Цена', null = True)
```

зависимая модель

```
class characterist_pkModel(models.Model):
    base_product = models.OneToOneField('productModel', on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField('Категория', max_length= 40, null= True)
```

И нужно `QuerySet` с записями модели `characterist_pkModel` отсортировать по полю `price` ,,родительской записи,, типа:

```
characterist_pkModel.objects.get(pk= 1).base_product.order_by('price')
```

но для целого QuerySet-а.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратите внимание, что все [имена классов](https://pep8.ru/doc/pep8/) должны следовать соглашению CapWords почти без исключений.

**Отвечая на ваш вопрос**

> Как отсортировать QuerySet по полю ,,OneToOneField,,?

Я немного изменил ваш код, суть вы должны понять.

```
class Price(models.Model):
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField('Цена', null=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.OneToOneField(Price, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Сортировку можно сделать следующим образом:

```
a = Product.objects.all().order_by('-price__price')
```

```
.order_by('-price__price') 
# - сортирока в обратном порядке
# price - связання модель
# __price - связанное поле модели
```

ссылка на оф. документацию: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/